# How do I set VLC media player as default video player?

Tags: vlc, default-programs

I can't seem to set VLC media player as the default video player. I have gone to *System Settings* → *System Info* → *Default Applications*, and changed "Video" to VLC media player.

However, all movies still open with Movie Player (Totem) by default. The video default application setting appears to have no effect. I have tried changing the setting and logging out/rebooting, but it doesn't appear to work.

Is there some command-line magic that can work on this?

Answer (score 93):

Go to *System Settings* → *System info* → *Default Applications*, and set it there. It works in Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot).

In Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) and later, it's found in *System Settings* → *Details* → *Default Applications*.

Comment: Even though the poster states clearly that this doesn't work?  I suspect that this only affect a certain extension - perhaps mp4.  (S)He's trying to open a matroska (mkv) file and default applications appears to be ignoring that.

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: In 13.04 it is in `System Settings/Details/Default Applications`

Comment: It's 2015, @ltn100's answer works in 15.10 too, can you update?

Answer (score 56):

Rightclick any video file, choose `properties`. Choose `Open With` and there you can select **VLC** and the option `set as default` (bottom right).

[image]

--

14.04 and 16.04 also has this option:

[image]

Comment: This step is to be done on all video filetypes. You can also replace `/usr/share/applications/totem.desktop` with `/usr/share/applications/vlc.desktop` to fool Ubuntu that VLC is Totem but I don't recommend this method.

Comment: No in 11.10 it is set for all video files iirc.

Comment: If your screenshot is correct, the step you've done is just for "Matroska video".

Comment: `Set as default` doesn't seem to be there in 13.04

Comment: @ltn100yes  there is. I added proof :+ Now remove the downvote.

Comment: @Rinzwind - I didn't see it in a fresh install of 13.04 as well when trying to set VLC as the default for MP4's. I had to go into `System Settings` > `Details` > `Default Applications` as suggested by Pyri to change it.

Comment: +comment above. this is not working in 13.10 either

Comment: In my version of 13.04 this works. Maybe they changed it?

Comment: I don't see this in ver 14.

Comment: Wow, it is very simple, It is working for Ubuntu 20.04 also.

Comment: Works for 22.04 as well

Answer (score 15):

### Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04

Click on the gear icon in the top right corner then select the option **About this computer**. From that set Vlc media player as default application for opening videos.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi! I set this (14.04) but nautilus has used totem (instead of vlc) yet. How can I set vlc as default for nautilus (and for gnome-disk-image-mounter too)?

Comment: follow the first answer.

Comment: thx Avinash Raj, but I have problem with dvd-s not video files, so that answer does not help me (if I think well)

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 12.10,   go to

"System Settings"
"Details"
"Default Applications"

CLick on the "down arrow" for "Video"

Select "VLC Media Player"

Then close window.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to assocoate all video mimetypes with vlc for current user, you can do this:

1. Check totem is currently default for all video mimetypes:

   ```
   cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep video
   ```

   You will see lines like this:

   ```
   video/x-avi=totem.desktop
   ```
2. Append all the lines containing video types to the local file:

   ```
   cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list | grep video >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
   ```
3. Replace all occurences of "=totem.desktop" with "=vlc.desktop" in vim, nano, geany or gedit. E.g. Search->Replace in gedit:

   ```
   gedit ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
   ```

P.S.: If you want to open audio by default in vlc too, then just replace "grep video" with "grep audio" and "=totem.desktop" with "=rhythmbox.desktop" in above 1,2,3.

Source: http://www.libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-ubuntu-linux

Comment: This works on Xubuntu as well.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the totem video player via ubuntu software center. It appears with name "Video". This will make every video format use VLC automatically.

Answer (score 2):

#### For 12.04

In Ubuntu Tweak under File Type Manager you can change and set the default for all media types and their specific formats.

Comment: Worked nicely for me. Allows you to set the default for all extensions at once.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by right click on the video file > **Open With Other Applications** > Right click on Banshee and click **Forget association**

I say Banshee, because I already uninstalled Totem in order to fix the issue.