# Can I connect totem/mplayer with my multimedia library as the default player?

Tags: multimedia, mp3, totem, mplayer, libraries

I am a huge fan of totem and mplayer and prefer their sound to other applications. I want to setup my multimedia library in such a way that when I play any multimedia file it should be played in totem/mplayer.

PS: I use Ubuntu 11.10.

PPS: I would really appreciate if I could get most of the functionalities of softwares such as Banshee and Rhythmbox if not all.

Comment: There are similar threads like:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/91701/how-to-set-vlc-as-default-video-player

Comment: I know how to set totem/mplayer as the default player. But, how do I get the library kind of functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is an library for this, but you can edit the file /etc/gnome/defaults.list to change the gnome behavior of default application.