# I want to set the default document viewer, but cannot change ImageMagick

Tags: 16.04, pdf, settings, default-programs

Set default document Viewer 
but no change ImageMagick(display).
I'm trying, but I can not change.
[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zBYf.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default program?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/90214/how-to-set-default-program) or [How to set VLC as default video player?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91701/how-to-set-vlc-as-default-video-player)