# Cannot change default music player 16.04

Tags: vlc, rhythmbox, file-association, preferences

I don't know if this is a bug, but I cannot change the default music player in 16.04 LTS.

In System Settings / Details / Preferred Applications, Rhythmbox is set as default, but when I double click the mp3 it opens VLC.

If I wish to change the default application, it doesn't change the VLC to Rhythmbox.

Is there a way I could do this through the terminal?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you use _Set as default_ in the last image?

Comment: Of course I did.

Comment: Checked the solutions here?  http://askubuntu.com/questions/91701/how-to-set-vlc-as-default-video-player

Comment: It's not default, as I cannot set it to default, it just switches back to VLC. And system settings show Rhythmbox but Mp3s and WAVs still open with VLC:

Comment: This occurs because there can be multiple mimetypes associated  for what you may think is just one type. One ex. would be audio/mp3 & audio/x-mp3. RB only registers the later. In gerenal it's better to just manually set a default player per type thru r. click on file > Properties, ect.. To reset to orig. defaults one would delete ~.config/mimetypes.list

Answer (score 0):

You can manage file type in Ubuntu-Tweak

**1).** Install `Ubuntu-Tweak` for **Ubuntu 16.04** (More info about [GetDeb Apps](http://www.getdeb.net/welcome/))

```
wget -q -O - http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb apps" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/getdeb.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak
```

**2).** Open `Ubuntu-Tweak` and go to Admins > File Type Manager:

[image]

In the categories press Audio and select which File Type will be open with `Rhythmbox`

Comment: How is this different than the method OP tried? Why would this work and others wouldn't?

Comment: Hello Anwar, thanks for your reply, ubuntu-tweak File Type Manager offers a wider range of file type. Give it a try!

Comment: This program is no longer maintained or supported, I highly suggest no one use it https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-tweak

Comment: Tried Ubuntu-Tweak, it won't switch to Rhythmbox when I try to change MP3 and WAV associations. Others do.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep Totem cat /usr/share/applications/defaults.list >> ~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Replace `org.gnome.Totem.desktop` with `mpv.desktop`

http://libre-software.net/change-the-default-application-linux-mint-ubuntu/