# Change the video DVD player of upper-right button displayed in Nautilus

Tags: 16.04, nautilus, dvd, video-player

[image]

In 16.04, when a DVD movie is accessed in Nautilus there is a button in the top right corner to play the movie in Totem.

Can this be replaced by other player like VLC or MPV?

---

This is not asking how to change the overall preferred application (as said above, under *Settings - Details - Default applications*), nor how to change the player per-file-type (under file's properties, "Open With"), therefore it is not a duplicate of [How do I set VLC media player as default video player?](https://askubuntu.com/q/91701/47206).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the application displayed there is the one selected under *Settings - Details - Removable media - DVD video* or, in case 'Ask what to do' or 'Open folder' is selected instead,  the first application displayed in that list.

The general solution seems to be simply to select a specific player (instead of "Ask what to do" or "Open folder") under *Settings - Details - Removable media - DVD video*. In this way that player will take the first position in that list even if "Ask what to do" or "Open folder" is selected afterwards.

[image]