# VLC not playing DVD and can't install libdvd-pkg in 20.10

Tags: vlc, 20.10

[image]It comes up with message "Are you trying to play dvd without libdvdcss?" I have tried all the command line fixes listed including the one that says it's for Ubuntu 20 but all return variations on "not found".  What am i missing?
Screen grab was taken from response and cut/pasted directly into terminal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I play encrypted DVD movies?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500/how-can-i-play-encrypted-dvd-movies)

Comment: Not really, as I said they will now play in Videos but VLC still refuses to play them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "multiverse" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89096/how-do-i-enable-the-multiverse-repository)

Comment: With the caveat above.  Yes I have enabled “mutiverse” but NO the other half of the original question is unanswered ie VLC will not play the DVD.

Comment: are you in Ubuntu  proper (gnome) using Nautilus as file manager? It's odd it says nothing when you insert the DVD.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` first then checked that you have all the packages necessary to play DVDs. Run `dpkg -l|grep libdvd`. You  should have installed libdvd-pkg, libdvdcss-dev, libdvdcss2, libdvdnav4 and libdvdread7.

Answer (score 2):

`libdvd-pkg` is in the multiverse repository; you need to enable that.

```
:~$apt policy libdvd-pkg
libdvd-pkg:
  Installed: 1.4.2-1-1
  Candidate: 1.4.2-1-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.4.2-1-1 500
        500 [redacted]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse amd64 Packages
        500 [redacted]/us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/multiverse i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

On my system (not 20.10) this can be done on the "Software and Updates" page.

[image]
After enabling multiverse, you will have to enter the following two commands one by one.

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Comment: Thank you that worked but it still won't play in VLC, although it does work in Videos now.

Comment: The OP has posted an answer that shows what the problem was really about: 1) no notification prompt/message upon insertion; 2) the OP was trying to play the DVD in VLC by opening individual files from the disk.

Answer (score 1):

Have since found that you must "Open DVD" not an individual file on said DVD.  VLC works if you do that doh!

Comment: Don't you get a message when you insert the DVD? You might be interested by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259729/341192), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/239762/341192), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/265874/341192).

Comment: This answer clarifies your question. You should edit the question to make it clear that the problem was with  you and VLC (hence your name I guess)

Comment: No message when DVD inserted and name is ironic arising from metal detecting.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes are faulty, I read "vlc" :) I hope my answer will count as compensation for my lack of attention. (Please edit your question: you get good answers that have nothing to do with your problem, it is a waste of people's time).

Comment: As you say,  `libdvd-pkg` in ubuntu 20.10 or any other OS  has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should be asked what to do when inserting a DVD. If you are not, check [the file manager settings](https://askubuntu.com/q/984824/925128).

Otherwise the command `vlc dvd://` should run the DVD. You could **associate that command with a shortcut**, or create a launcher for it. If Gedit is your text editor (if you are in Ubuntu proper - Gnome), do this:

- Create the folder  `~/.local./share/applications` (CTRL+h to see hidden files and folders)
- Open terminal and run `gedit ~/.local./share/applications/start_dvd_vlc` (that should open the newly created file `~/.local./share/applications/start_dvd_vlc`. If it doesn't then you have another text editor; you can replace `gedit` with that or install gedit with `sudo apt install gedit`).

Paste this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Play DVD in VLC media player
Exec=vlc dvd://
Icon=vlc
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=AudioVideo;Player;Recorder;
Keywords=Player;Capture;DVD;Audio;Video;Server;Broadcast;
```

If you want a different icon for that, change the `Icon` line to the path  to your icon. Take a look [here](https://iconarchive.com/search?q=vlc%20dvd). This might work:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Save the file.

If you are interested in using other players, see [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/265881/341192).

Use application launcher (Super key) with "VLC" or "DVD" to find the launcher "Play DVD in VLC media player".

I'm in Xfce, so it looks like this:

[image]

In Xfce, the Whisker Menu launcher can add a separate new "search action" that can run any command, including those discussed above:

[image]

[image]