# 20.04 and still not able to play DVD

Tags: dvd

So. I'm trying to play dvds. But it won't work.

I've installed restricted and libdvdfiles and gstreamer.

I've also tried VLC and the player that came with ubuntu install.

They both recognize the dvd. The built in player won't play because it's encrypted. VLC tries to load but nothing happends and one can hear the plate is spinning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VLC not playing DVD and can't install libdvd-pkg in 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1294860/vlc-not-playing-dvd-and-cant-install-libdvd-pkg-in-20-10)

Comment: libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.2-1-

Comment: Does this work? https://askubuntu.com/a/892167/124466

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libdvdnav4 is already the newest version (6.0.1-1build1).
libdvdread7 is already the newest version (6.1.0+really6.0.2-1).
libdvd-pkg is already the newest version (1.4.2-1-1).
... and no... It doesn't.. but I thank you for your feedback.

Comment: Did you try entering this command?
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Comment: result: libdvd-pkg: guest package [libdvdcss2/1.4.2-1~local] is already installed.

Comment: You said "gstreamer" - do you mean [these](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/27971/11700) two packages? Could you please edit your question to include the specific packages you installed?

Comment: To play encrypted DVDs, merely install libdvdcss2. This solves most problems.